# Prevent empty elements in list when using an OR statement with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm compiling prices from a website using regex.

```
PriceFinder = re.compile('(?<=\n\s\<b>\$)(\d*\.\d{2})(?=\<\/)|(?<=\"FF0000"><b>\$)(\d*\.\d{2})(?=\<\/)')
Price = re.findall(PriceFinder, str(soup))
print Price
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
[('', '30.99'), ('', '30.99'), ('', '30.99'), ('34.99', ''), ('34.99', '')
```

I would like to know what I have to add to my regex in order to obtain a list without any empty element.

```
['30.99','30.99','30.99','34.99','34.99']
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `(?<=\n\s\<b>\$|\"FF0000"><b>\$)(\d*\.\d{2})(?=\<\/)`?

Comment: `raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: How about `(?:(?<=\n\s\<b>\$)|(?<=\"FF0000"><b>\$))(\d*\.\d{2})(?=\<\/)`?

Comment: Or even `(?:\n\s\<b>\$|\"FF0000"><b>\$)(\d*\.\d{2})(?=\<\/)` for that matter. From reading the docs on `findall` it seems that if groups are present it will return only the groups.

Comment: The last two do the job perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've written my first python to answer this question:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

r = re.compile('(?:\n\s\<b>\$|\"FF0000"><b>\$)(\d*\.\d{2})(?=\<\/)')
p = re.findall(r, '<x y="FF0000"><b>$30.99</b></x>\n <b>$31.99</b>')
print p
```

prints out `['30.99', '31.99']`